# Failed to fetch localhost/api (next.js, Open AI)

Tags: node.js, cors, connection, fetch-api

Every time I run my client side of the directory, I get an error that it **failed to fetch 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post'** which is part of my server side of the directory. The server side seems to work well (with the message: Server has started,
MongoDB connected).

[My index.js file in server directory]

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use('/api/v1/post', postRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/dalle', dalleRoutes);


app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from DALL-E!');
})

const startServer = async() => {
    try {
        connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
        app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server has started on port http://localhost:8080'))
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    
};
```

[Client page that seems to be the problem]

```
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
        if (response.ok){
          const result = await response.json();
          setAllPosts(result.data.reverse());        
      }
     } catch(error){
        alert(error)
      } finally{
        setLoading(false);
      }

    };
```

[Server: postRoutes.js]

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary';

import Post from '../mongodb/models/post.js';

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,

});


//GET ALL POSTS
router.route('/').get(async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const posts = await Post.find({});
        res.status(200).json({success: true, data: posts})
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false, message: 'Fetching post failed, please try again'})

    }
});

//CREATE A POST
router.route('/').post(async(req, res) => {
    try{
    const {name , prompt, photo} = req.body;
    const photoUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(photo);

    const newPost = await Post.create({
        name,
        prompt,
        photo: photoUrl.url,
    })
    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: newPost});

    } catch (error){
        res.status(500).json({success: false, message:'Unable to create a post, please try again' })

    }
    });
export default router;
```

I installed Cors and implemented it in py index.js in my server side. I don't know what is causing the error. I am new to using next.js, and I can't figure out the error on my own. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The endpoint is `/api/post` or `/api/v1/post`?

Comment: the error says /api/v1/post and the end point is /api/v1/post as well- I just fixed the question

Comment: Can you show the code of `postRoutes`?

Comment: Yeah i just added it to the question!

Comment: both /api/v1/post and /api/v1/dalle don't work but I don't know why :(